# Bar chart - counting and aggregating by categorical values in a column usiong matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Im trying to get counts of categories in a category column, and then sum of the values for each category.
In Seaborn the count is  simple with a countplot, but Id like to do it in matplotlib directly.

Is it a case where i simply have to create a new dataframe with a column for each category?

Ive given an image with sample dataset & sample of what im trying to accomplish.

Appreciate any advise on the technique for achieving this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    data.groupby(['Category']).sum().plot(ax=ax, kind='bar')
    plt.title('Sum of Categories')

    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()
    data['Category'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax2,kind='bar')
    plt.title('Count of Categories')
```